# What is the performance implications of nested hashes in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mlab

So I have a very large set of metrics (15GB and growing) that has some of the data in nested hashes. Like so:

```
{
   _id: 'abc0000',
   type: 'foo',
   data: { a: 20, b: 30, c: 3 }
},
... more data following this schema...
{
   _id: 'abc5000',
   type: 'bar'
   data: { a: 1,  b: 2,  c: 4, d: 10 }
}
```

What is the performance implications when I run a query on the nested hashes? The data inside the hash can't be indexed...or rather, it would be pointless to index it.

I can always reform the data into a flat style `data_a`, `data_b`, etc...

Comment: Does this query include primary key or rather you'll query all documents?

Comment: I'll be querying a range of data and occasionally aggregating data. When a write happens, does Mongo block until complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create indexes on attributes in nested hashes. Take a look at [Indexing with dot notation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-IndexingonEmbeddedFields%28%22DotNotation%22%29) for more details. You can also create compound indexes if you need, but be careful about [caveats with parallel arrays](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Multikeys#Multikeys-CaveatswithParallelArrays). Basically, if you create a compound index only one of the indexed values can be array, however, that shouldn't effect you(judging from posted schema).

So you can create indexes on `data.a`, `data.b` or `data.a, data.c` as per your needs.